# Código C# para SearchBar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

estou tentando criar uma searchBar no meu código. É apenas para entender a estrutura e sintaxe dos comandos. Apos seguir alguns tutoriais, cheguei na seguinte estrutura (em anexo).
A IDE está retornando erro na para "where", informando que não é um comando e não tem nenhuma definição. 
Alguém sabe me dizer como solucionar?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta importar o namespace

> [System.Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.8)